# How do I place dot on system path (graphviz related)?

Tags: graphviz, python-3.7

I'm running graphviz per an online tutorial, but ran into an error: ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tried reinstalling on anaconda onto PATH environment. Doesn't work. Is any kind soul able to guide amateur here? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Code used

```
from sklearn import tree
import graphviz

tree_graph = tree.export_graphviz(tree_model, out_file=None, feature_names=feature_names)
graphviz.Source(tree_graph)
```

Comment: Have you installed the Graphviz app in your system? http://graphviz.org/

Comment: @Dany. Yes. I downloaded graphviz-2.38.zip from here <graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html>. <br/> I used the following code to overcome the issue. import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'